# Changing DictMixin.iterkeys to MutableMapping

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm looking to use OrderedDict in my code since the Ruby version of this project uses YAML for maps and settings but OrderedDict hasn't been updated for Python 3.

The Ruby version of the project uses this file: https://mega.co.nz/#!zhYRwA4B!HceqC3-NmmN44U70--jMxiAWQ4wz5MdAeilteKAOnSM

I changed the import lines to read as:

```
from collections import UserDict
from collections import MutableMapping as DictMixin
```

I already know v3 doesn't make use of iterkeys so how would I change iterkeys to something MutableMapping understands?

```
iterkeys = DictMixin.iterkeys
itervalues = DictMixin.itervalues
iteritems = DictMixin.iteritems
```

I've seen many examples of how to change it but I don't understand how to use them here.

Maybe I should use something else for YAML file support in Python 3, perhaps?

Edit: I called my file yaml.py. I shouldn't have done that.
I also had a file path in there it didn't like. I've removed it and it works.

Edit 2: I've just realised I've screwed up my question. It should have been about OMAPs in Python not YAML. I'll open a different question for that. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: What do you mean by "OrderedDict hasn't been updated for Python 3"?

Comment: Do you mean some other ordered dict than [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to Python and I'm looking for something which can read the YAML files I have. The YAML files are used for displaying the map terrain, user settings, etc. Would using collections.OrderedDict be suitable for it?

Comment: Can you provide some working example? Input file, what do you have right now and expected output.

Comment: Pyaml http://pyyaml.org/ supports  python3 since 2008.

Comment: @zero323 I meant the OrderedDict file I was using from PyPi. My bad!

Comment: So what is the connection between OrderedDict and YAML files support? I want to read YAML, use pyymal. If you want OrderedDict why not use collections.OrderedDict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step:

1. Create python 3 vitrtualenv

   ```
   mkvirtualenv -p python3 testyaml
   ```
2. Install pyaml inside virtualenv

   ```
   pip install pyaml
   ```
3. Now create some yaml file (example from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Examples):

   ```
   receipt:     Oz-Ware Purchase Invoice
   date:        2012-08-06
   customer:
       given:   Dorothy
       family:  Gale

   items:
       - part_no:   A4786
         descrip:   Water Bucket (Filled)
         price:     1.47
         quantity:  4

       - part_no:   E1628
         descrip:   High Heeled "Ruby" Slippers
         size:      8
         price:     100.27
         quantity:  1

   bill-to:  &id001
       street: |
               123 Tornado Alley
               Suite 16
       city:   East Centerville
       state:  KS

   ship-to:  *id001

   specialDelivery:  >
       Follow the Yellow Brick
       Road to the Emerald City.
       Pay no attention to the
       man behind the curtain.
   ```
4. And python script

   ```
   import yaml

   d = yaml.load(open('foo.yaml'))

   print(d.keys())
   print(d.values())
   ```
5. Run script

   ```
   python3 foo.py
   ```
6. Check results